# Обрезать строку с конца Javascript

Tags: строки, javascript, синтаксический-анализ

Как мне обрезать строку с конца по какой-то определенный символ?
Например: есть ссылка `http://127.0.0.1/product/price/new/4` 
как мне ее обрезать до вида `http://127.0.0.1/product/` ???
Может как то надо воспользоваться `split` но как не доходит. То есть мне надо обрезать слово до третьего слеша с начала, это константа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/product/price/new/4';
url = url.split('/').slice(0, 4).join('/')+'/';

// или (может кто-то красивее предложит)
url = url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/([^/]+\/){2}).*/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 3):

можно replace:

```
string.replace(/^(([^\/]*\/){4,4}).*/,'$1')
```

---

```
^(([^\/]*\/){4,4}).*
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Редактировать](http://www.debuggex.com/r/1QmiJuQz6p7qnY39)